# Why the Python memory error using shutil.copyfileobj?

Tags: python-3.x, memory, copy, buffer, shutil

I created an in-memory file and then tried to save it as a file:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

# various calculations
with open(s_outfile, "w") as outfile:
    # make a header row
    outfile.write('npi,NPImatched,lookalike_npi,domain,dist,rank\n')

stream_out = StringIO()

for i in big_iterator
    # more calculations, creating dataframe df_info
    df_info.to_csv(stream_out, index=False, header=False)

with open(s_outfile, 'a', newline='\n') as file:
    stream_out.seek(0)
    shutil.copyfileobj(stream_out, file)
stream_out.close()
```

The point of writing inside the loop to the `StringIO` object was to to speed up `df_info.to_csv()`, which worked ok (but less dramatically than I expected).  But when I tried to copy the in-memory object to a file with `shutil.copyfileobj()`, I got `MemoryError`, with essentially no further information.

It's a large-ish situation; the loop runs about 1M times and the output data should have had a size of about 6GB.  This was running on a GCP Linux compute instance with (I think) about 15GB RAM, although of course less than that (and perhaps less than the size of the in-memory data object) was free at the time.

But why would I get a memory error?  Isn't `shutil.copyfileobj()` all about copying incrementally, using memory safely, and avoiding excessive memory consumption?  I see now that it has an optional buffer size parameter, but as far as I can see, it defaults to something much smaller than the scale I'm working at with this data.

Would you expect the error to be avoided if I simply set the buffer size to something moderate like 64KB?  Is my whole approach wrong-headed?  It takes long enough to get the in-memory data established that I can't test things willy-nilly.  Thanks in advance.